# How to reload the tableView after dismissing a NavigationController in uisplitviewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm using a `UISplitviewController` as a template.

action for edit button:

```
newExViewController *editWindow =[[newExViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"newExViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:editWindow];
navBar.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
navBar.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:navBar animated:YES];
[navBar release];

[editWindow release];
```

`navBar` has a `UIBarButton` for saveButton. This is called when you press SaveButton

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

now is the problem: 
any idea how to reload the data for both the main NavigationConteroller and the detailViewController when the modalView is dismissed??
I have no clue
thnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into [`NSNotificationCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In your view with the UITableView, create the notification listener. Then in the view that dismisses, call that notification.

To be more specific, the Notification will call a method that should contain `reloadData`.

### Example

The following should go with the UITableView you want to reload:

This could go along with your `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethodToReloadTable) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
```

This is how you will call the notification center to reload the table:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTable" object:self];
```

Example of the notification method:

```
- (void)someMethodToReloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    [myTableView reloadData];  
}
```

And don't forget to remove the notificaiton observer:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: It worked great. Thank you :D, I was able to reload both the detailview and the rootview. Fantastic

Comment: Hi so I'm trying to do the same, but wasn't sure where to place the notificationcenter. Should it go on the rootviewcontroller's class? or the tableview (on the rootview) itself?

Answer (score 3):

In controllers, that contains view you want to reload, you should decline following method which will be called when the `modalView` will be dismissed (or when controller's main view will be first time loaded):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // here you can reload needful views, for example, tableView:
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: viewWillAppear or viewdidappear wont be called after you dismiss a modalViewControler