# objective-c reload UITableView after back navigation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, navigation, reload, nsnotification

I have a `TableViewController` embedded in a `NavigationController`, at some point I use a `Segue` to `push` to a new `ViewController`. When I navigate back from the `ViewController` I want to reload the `tableView` in the `TableViewController`.

I followed the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303219/how-to-reload-the-tableview-after-dismissing-a-navigationcontroller-in-uisplitvi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c). For some reason it does not work. I miss something but I can't see it at the moment.

Has anybody a glue, why the code does not work? What do I have to do to get it work?

#### TableViewController.m

```c
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // notification when comeing back from the cameraView
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMagazine:) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];

    }
    return self;
} 
//[...]
// notification reload
-(void)reloadMagazine:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"notification reload");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
//[...]

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTable" object:self];
}
```

#### ViewController.m

```c
-(void)uploadData:(id)sender {    
    // Upload and navigate back to the tableViewController
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTable" object:self];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: and certainly you should not be calling both dismissViewControllerAnimated AND popViewControllerAnimated.  Stick to the former.

Comment: ... and you should *remove*  the observer somewhere, probably in `dealloc`.

Comment: i thought `viewWillAppear` is not called when navigating back. Will try this.

Comment: Worked with `viewWillAppear`. Thanks. Removed `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, `popViewControllerAnimated` works fine alone. The other way round it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer your question *"why the code does not work?"*, but the easiest
method to reload the table view when navigating back to it could be to
call `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the code above does not work because initWithStyle is not being called.   Put a breakpoint there to test my theory.   If that is the case, then move that code to viewDidLoad.