# Using NSNotificationCenter to refresh tableView on dismissModalViewController

Tags: uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I am using the UIImagePickerController to add photos to an app directory of photos and plans, with the parent ViewController being a tableViewController. I had the problems reported elsewhere of the table not refreshing with the added file on dismissModalViewController, and I've read that dismissModalViewController doesn't trigger viewWillAppear in the parent controller, and I saw [@WrightCS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171206/wrightscs) answer using NSNotificationCenter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303219/how-to-reload-the-tableview-after-dismissing-a-navigationcontroller-in-uisplitvi). However, when I tried it I got the following:

***-[MapTableViewController someMethodToReloadTable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d5ca330***

The code I've used is here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.mapPath = delegate.mapPath;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethodToReloadTable) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
```

........

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    pageSize = image.size;
    CGRect imageBoundsRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
     NSString *path = [self.mapPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"image.pdf"];


    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:path];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"dismiss  triggered");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTable" object:self];
    NSLog(@"notification fired");



}

- (void)someMethodToReloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification
{ NSLog(@"notification  triggered");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `someMethodToReloadTable` method takes an argument, so your selector in `viewDidLoad` needs a `:`.

Change:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethodToReloadTable) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
```

to:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethodToReloadTable:) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. It didn't crash, but neither did it refresh. I then had to force a reload by recalculating the number of files within the someMethodToReloadTable method. That worked.